# Create folders from files into another folder (bash)

Tags: bash

I need some help to deal with folders and file in linux.

```
path1/path2/file_1:



file_A.txt 
file_B.txt 
file_C.txt 
file_D.txt
```

and I would like from this `file_1` to create one folder for each `file_X.txt` and put inside the corresponding `file_X.txt`
so for this exemple I should get 4 new folders in the big folder "`Project`" that got the name of the `file_X.txt` without the `.txt` part:

```
/Project/file_A
    file_A.txt

/Project/file_B
    file_B.txt

/Project/file_C
    file_C.txt

/Project/file_D
    file_D.txt
```

*Note that the folder `Project` does not exist yet.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: To clarify, as both answers seem to assume otherwise: are `file_A.txt`, `file_B.txt` etc. the *contents* of `file_1`?

Comment: Do `path1/path2/file_1` is a text file contain `file_A.txt`  ... `file_D.txt`  as text? right?
Where is the files are located you want to get moved into the folders later? or you just want to touch an empty file there named as the folder + .txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below should do what you need :

```
for file in $(find /path/to/files/ -name "file_*.txt") 
do 
  name=$(basename "$file" .txt) 
  mkdir -p /Project/$name 
  mv "$file" /Project/$name  
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Check This

```
for i in *.txt 
do  
  bname=$(basename -- $i)
  filename=${bname%.*}
  mkdir $filename 
  mv $i $filename
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't tell if you are trying to build a directory structure from a list of files that is stored in a text file or move existing files to a new directory structure.

The other answers show how to build a directory structure and move exisitng files.

If you need to build a directory structure from a list, creating new empty files, you could do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

manifest=/path1/path2/file_1 # Path to the file containing the list of files to create
parent=./Project # Path to the parent directory for the new sub-directories

while read -r filename; do
    basename="${filename%.txt}"
    mkdir -p "${parent}/${basename}"
    touch "${parent}/${basename}/$filename"
done < "$manifest"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help